# Angular5 - Scrolling to anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5, anchor-scroll

I am trying to do a scroll to an anchor when I redirect to a new page. I have tried different things but without success. Now it scrolls down but it's not showing the whole HTML element I need, it shows only the header of the element.
Here is the redirect to the new page

```
this.router.navigate(['/controllo/' + result.id], {fragment: 'assegnazioneContatto'});
```

And here is how I scroll to the element

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeParams.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
        if(window.document.getElementById(fragment)) {
          this.fragment = fragment; 
          window.document.getElementById(this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
       }
      });
}
```

Here is the HTML element

```
<div class="row" [hidden]="!showAssegnazioneContatto()" id="assegnazioneContatto"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen other questions here in stackoverflow but I haven't found any solution.

PS. If I run the code in the console it works fine

Answer (score 0):

From your question I have understood that the scroll is behaving in a way that it shows most of the preceding elements and the beginning of your new element.

Does this jsFiddle illustrate your situation? https://jsfiddle.net/eqzkpr8a/3/

Try playing around with the `scrollIntoView()`'s options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#parameters. Specially the **block** property, which defines the vertical alignment of the page based on its ancestor element.

In other words, the **block** property may have four possible values: *start*, *center*, *end*, and *nearest*.
The properties align the page vertically

- *start*: at the start of its ancestor element;
- *center*: at the center of its ancestor element;
- *end*: at the end of its ancestor element;
- *nearest*: towards the *start* or the *end* of its ancestor element, based on whatever is nearest to the scrolled element.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but nothing worked

Comment: could you try instantiating the element as a ViewChild and then performing the `.scrollIntoView()` on its .nativeElement? i.e. @ViewChild('assegnazioneContatto') assegnazioneDiv(): ElementRef; (...) ngOnInit() { this.assegnazioneDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({block:'start'}); }

Answer (score 0):

Two options. Have you tried .focus({ preventScroll: false }) or have you tried setting tabindex="1" of the element? Because I had to do that for my own scroll function to have it working properly.

Comment: I tried `tabindex="1"` didn't work. While trying `window.document.getElementById(this.fragment).focus({ preventScroll: false })` gives me this error "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: In my code I don't use window, just document. Not sure why you get an error? The .focus() method can take arguments

Comment: If I run the code in the console works fine also with document. I don't know why is giving me the error